# How to Automate - Ticking Boxes on a Website

Tags: python, html, xpath, pyautogui

I am trying to come up with Python code that automates ticking a box on a website.

I have used Python Autogui - to copy a number from an Excel spreadsheet. This code works fine.

Then I would like to go to a particular website and tick that corrosponding number.

For example if I have the number '3' that I have copied I would like to tick box number '3'.

1.☐
4.☐
6.☐
3.☒
8.☐

Note that the tick boxes aren't in order.

I have looked at the corrosponding HTML behind the tick boxes on the website - but I cannot figure out how to put an actual tick in the box.

**I am after the code that takes the copied number and ticks the corrosponding box.**

Also - I would like to avoid using Selenium if possible - because after the boxes are ticked I need to log into the website - which doesn't happen because the website doesn't allow login when controlled by Selenium.

Below is the related HTML:

**HTML that relates to the number 3**

```
<span class="size14_f7opyze Endeavour_fhudrb0 medium_f1wf24vo">3. Prince Of Helena</span>
```

**HTML for the tick box:**

```
<i data-automation-id="correctIsolated" class="icon_f1n94a56 boxedSelectInput_f3llvvk correctIsolated_fb6aqe6 SIZE_14_f7opyze"></i>
```

**All HTML**

```
<div class="outcomeDetailsContainer_f13tqi60"><img data-automation-id="racecard-outcome-silk" class="jockeySilk_fdg2pgk" src="https://i.sbstatic.com.au/silks/5fbb9068cc1cedd1dc29ede80f3a751c_large.gif"><div class="outcomeDetails_fgw55bl"><div class="runnerInfoOuter_f1rhfno9"><div class="outcomeName_f18x6kvm" data-automation-id="racecard-outcome-name"><span class="size14_f7opyze Endeavour_fhudrb0 medium_f1wf24vo">3. Prince Of Helena</span><span class="size11_fwt0xu4 Endeavour_fhudrb0 light_f2noysy">&nbsp;(4)</span></div><div class="runnerInfo_f61y1ps" data-automation-id="racecard-outcome-info"><div class="runnerInfoCont_f1op6hsi"><span class="size11_fwt0xu4 light_f2noysy runnerInfoDetails_f5rbj1u">W: 59.5kg</span><span class="size11_fwt0xu4 light_f2noysy runnerInfoDetails_f5rbj1u">F: 313423</span></div><div class="runnerJockeyInfo_f1n4s149"><span class="runnerJockeyCont_f1f1ygnm"><span class="size11_fwt0xu4 light_f2noysy runnerInfoDetailsEllipsis_f6qpmtj" data-automation-id="racecard-outcome-info-jockey">J: Jake Duffy</span></span><span class="size11_fwt0xu4 light_f2noysy runnerInfoDetailsEllipsis_f6qpmtj" data-automation-id="racecard-outcome-info-trainer">T: Craig Weeding</span></div></div></div><div class="priceContainer_f1f1ygnm"><div class="exoticsButtons_f1686pjc"><div class="selectionContainer_f1hf8rho"><div class="checkbox_f1ih5r2b"><div data-automation-id="racecard-exotic-668021620-1-on" class="selectedUnboxed_f1uwc4pi"><div class="buttonContainer_fdhhify"><div class="plainCheckRippleContainer_fsae94r"><div class="border_fyn86re"><div class="rippleGroup_f18snavk"><div class="quick_fl0fses blue_f1co9fm7 entered_fhxh0lv" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></div><div class="quick_fl0fses blue_f1co9fm7 entered_fhxh0lv" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></div><div class="quick_fl0fses blue_f1co9fm7 entered_fhxh0lv" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></div><div class="quick_fl0fses blue_f1co9fm7 entered_fhxh0lv" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></div><div class="quick_fl0fses blue_f1co9fm7 entered_fhxh0lv" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></div></div></div></div><div class="plainSelected_f1f8aai0 button_f1qfakw5"><i data-automation-id="correctIsolated" class="icon_f1n94a56 boxedSelectInput_f3llvvk correctIsolated_fb6aqe6 SIZE_14_f7opyze"></i></div></div></div></div></div><div class="exoticsButtonContainer_fwthz3w" data-automation-id="racecard-exotic-outcome-0-L-price"><div class="priceLabelWrapper_f18m2cag" data-automation-id="undefinedoutcome"><div class="priceLabelContent_f1c1vytv"><span class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo">1.65</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

[image]

I am fairly green with Python and HTML - so if you have any tips on how to better convey my question don't hesitate. Thanks in advance.

Angus

Comment: please share the html with the boxes

Comment: Question now includes HTML for the boxes  - thankyou

Comment: Have you considered using Selenium?

Comment: Have you considered using Selenium?
`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('"span[data-automation-id='correctIsolated']")

Comment: I'd rather not use Selenium since once I have selected the tick box I need to log in - and this particular website does not allow login whislt web site is 'automated'

Comment: Your All HTML example does not resemble the boxes.  Or you change your examples accordingly or give a url to a live page.

Comment: If you don't want to use selenium, I suggest using image detection techniques. And you could do the following.

Firstly, detect all the boxes with the `locateAllOnScreen` method. Once you've done that, detect the 3. With a simple `locateOnScreen`. 

Lastly, get the box which is closest in the X axis to the 3 you detected. And finally click on the coordinates. If you need help with the code I'll provide an answer.